# The dispensivity of the definition for exhaustion by compact sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, Why?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[In the Wikipedia's Page is wrote:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exhaustion_by_compact_sets)

Exhaustion by compact sets of an open set $U$ in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an increasing sequence of compact sets ${\displaystyle K_{j}}\subseteq U$, where by increasing we mean ${\displaystyle K_{j}}\subseteq{\displaystyle K_{j+1}}$, with the limit (union) of the sequence being $U$ (i.e. $U=\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty K_j$).

Sometimes one requires the sequence of compact sets to satisfy one more property—that ${\displaystyle K_{j}}$ is contained in the interior of ${\displaystyle K_{j+1}}$ for each ${\displaystyle j}$. This, however, is dispensed in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My question:

I am confused and I do not understand why in $\mathbb{R}^n$, ${\displaystyle K_{j}}$ is contained in the interior of ${\displaystyle K_{j+1}}$ is dispensed. Is it right? Why?

Comment: So am I.  What, in this context does dispensed mean?

Comment: I do not know, exactly. Probably, it means cancel or exempt or forgive and so on.

Comment: There is no agreement in the literature on this requirement: Some authors require that $K_j\subset int(K_{j+1})$ and some do not. Why the author of the linked wikipedia article chose the latter convention, I do not know. The thing is, $R^n$ (and every open subset of thereof) admits an exhaustion by compact subsets, understood in the former sense.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan. I guess that any exhaustion by compact sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ automatically has the property $K_j\subset int(K_{j+1})$. Is it right?

Comment: @bigli: No, this is not true, if you use the wikipedia definition of exhaustion. You can easily make examples already in the case of $n=1$. One can even find examples where there is no $j$ such that $K_1\subset int(K_j)$ for  any $j> 1$.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan. May you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to think about. Let $n=1$. Consider the family of compact subsets $K_i\subset {\mathbb R}$ given by
$$
K_i=[-i, - i^{-1}]\cup \{0\} \cup [i^{-1}, i]. 
$$
This family forms an exhaustion of ${\mathbb R}$ by compact subsets (in the sense of the Wikipedia article), such that for all $i$, $j$, $K_i$ is not  contained in the interior of $K_j$.

Comment: @ Moishe Kohan. Thanks for the time you spent. In addition, I think that the definition of exhaustion by compact sets (in the sense of the Wikipedia article) is not interesting and applicable.

Comment: @bigli: Yes, I suggest using the more standard definition. The one from the linked Wikipedia page was originally written by a computer programmer with MA in math.